# Tablepress CSS column formatting issue

Tags: css

First I'm not a programmer, please be gentle. I have tried several methods to change the first column, in all tables, to stop wrapping text. Now the column doesn't bold the date and the text is extremely small. Below is the code. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
.tablepress td {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    font-size: 100%;
}

.tablepress td strong {
    font-size: 80%;
}

.person {
    color: #930252;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.entry-content .tablepress {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto 1em;
}

.tablepress-id-12 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-13 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-28 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-27 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-34 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-35 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-36 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-64 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-65 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-67 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-68 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-71 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-72 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-63 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-69 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-82 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-37 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-84 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-85 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-101 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-99 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-102 .column-1 {
    font-size: 300%;
    min-width: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16478749/4330693

```
.tablepress td:nth-of-type(1) {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    font-size: 14px; <-- optional
}
```

Also, if you wish to change the font size use `em, rem, px` or `vw`.

`font-size: 14px`

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to do this.

A table has a structure of rows and columns.

Rows are the `<tr>` elements. Inside a `<tr>` you have two options to use, a `<th>` usually used for headers and a `<td>` usually used for content.

So, if you have a table like this:

```css
.table thead tr th:first-child {
  background-color: blue;
  color: cyan;
}

.table tbody tr td:first-child {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.6.1/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Person Name</th>
       <th>Person Age</th>
       <th>Actions</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td><a>Edit</a> <a>Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td><a>Edit</a> <a>Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td><a>Edit</a> <a>Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td><a>Edit</a> <a>Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td><a>Edit</a> <a>Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you might have seen, CSS works with selectors, there are simpler ones and more complex ones. In this case the one you need is first-child. Since there's no column definition for the entire table, what you want to do is affect each first column of each row.

That's what the `tr td:first-child` rule does. I added some more specificity just for the example.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm grateful for this help.

Comment: Did the answer work for you? Do you need more help with this?

Comment: I actually need more help. Now my font sizes are huge. Here is the code I have. My sense is that the code is really not written well and that is the beginning of the problem..tablepress-table-name {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ff0000;
}

Comment: @rstjames the code might be related to the percentage font-sizes, could you update your question and add your current code, so that I can check it. Also, an image preview of how it currently looks or a snippet would be useful.

Comment: Mihail, Thank you so much for helping. I have moved forward and now I've used a padding at the end of the code to make sure that the first column does not wrap the text. This made the lines between cells vanish, which I do not want. Here is my current code..person. (Not sure where to put the new code) Man I'm sorry I know this has to be frustrating for you.

Comment: You can edit your original question and either modify the code there or add some more text with the update :) @rstjames